# html: {id: 'query'} doesn't work in form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In a html form generated with Ruby, I wish to use a custom id attribute values.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {id: 'basic_form'}) do |f| %>
```

but it is not working, and the id value is the default generated by Ruby.

Please point me to the right direction. Thank you!

UPDATE (Solved):
I guess the problem was somewhere else in the code. rolled back to previous code backup and did code changes again. It worked with the same above code. Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: That should work well, tell us which Rails version.

Comment: rails version 4.1.0

Comment: all I can think of is try switching or dropping some other arguments to see if there is interference that we're missing. That should definitely be working as is

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name),:id => 'basic_form' do |f| %>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The output is still the same:     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">

Comment: why you need to change the id ?

Comment: The registration page dynamically renders two different forms based on the parameters passed in the url. one for free membership, and another for paid membership. By default, both the forms have same id. So, I have to manually change id of one of the form, to make sure the correct form gets selected in the javascript which handles payment api.

Comment: ok, I tried the same syntax that you mention in your question & its working at my end, I am using rails 5 app.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.1.0, it's not possible to upgrade rails version right now due to compatibility.

Comment: if you want to check ref : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise in section Configuring views

Comment: scoped_views didn't help. still the same output with default ids.

Comment: Even in devise docs for version rails 4 , they have mention the above syntax

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation